# Django sum two columns with conditions using mysql raw query and render value to template

Tags: django

Please I need assistance on how to use Django to sum two columns with conditions using mysql raw query.

Am just a newbie

I need somtin select sum(amt), sum(qty) from table where transid=7

How can I use Django raw mysql query to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Django's raw SQL query using QuerySet, you can use the raw() method

Let's hope your model looks like this

```py
from django.db import models

class Transaction(models.Model):
    amt = models.IntegerField()
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    transid = models.IntegerField()

# Let's say, your table name is `transaction`

raw_query = "SELECT SUM(amt) as total_amt, SUM(qty) as total_qty FROM transaction WHERE transid = %s"

# Execute the raw SQL query using a QuerySet
result = Transaction.objects.raw(raw_query, [7])

for row in result:
    print(row.total_amt)
    print(row.total_qty)
```

[More on django queryset raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/)

If you don't want to use queryset you can use the django db connections to perform raw query

```py
from django.db import connections

def get_transactions():
    with connections.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT SUM(amt), SUM(qty) FROM transaction WHERE transid = %s', [7])
        result = cursor.fetchone()

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Django's raw SQL query feature, you can execute virtually any SQL query directly against your database. Here's how you can achieve the query you mentioned using Django's raw query capability:

First, ensure you have a model that corresponds to the table you're querying. For instance, if your table is named `MyTable`, you should have a Django model for it. Let's assume you have a model named `MyModel`.

Then, you can execute your raw SQL query as follows:

```
from django.db import connection
from myapp.models import MyModel  # Replace 'myapp' with your     actual app name

trans_id = 7
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(amt), SUM(qty) FROM my_table WHERE      transid = %s", [trans_id])
result = cursor.fetchone()

sum_amt, sum_qty = result
```

Here's a breakdown of the code:

1. **Import the necessary modules**: Import `connection` from `django.db` and your model from the appropriate app.
2. **Prepare Your Query**: Write your SQL query. Here, we use `%s` as a placeholder for the `transid` value. This is a parameterized query, which is a good practice to avoid SQL injection attacks.
3. **Execute the Query**: Use `cursor.execute()` to run your SQL query. The `trans_id` variable is passed as a parameter.
4. **Fetch the Result**: `cursor.fetchone()` retrieves the first row of the result set, which in your case is the summed values.
5. **Extract the Values**: The result is a tuple containing the sums. You can unpack these into `sum_amt` and `sum_qty`.

Replace `'my_table'` with the actual name of your table. If you're following Django's naming conventions, it's typically the lowercased name of your model. Also, replace `MyModel` with the name of your actual model.

Remember, direct SQL queries bypass many of Django's ORM protections and features, so they should be used judiciously and carefully, especially in production environments. Always validate and sanitize any inputs to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.